# Is it true? The inequality $\frac{pa+qb}{a+b} \le p+q$,

Tags: real-analysis

The inequality $\dfrac{pa+qb}{a+b} \le p+q$, where $p,q:R_+\times [0,c]\to R_+$ and $a,b>0. $

Comment: One proof is simply to notice that $a/(a + b)$ and $b/(a + b)$ are both less than $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{pa+qb}{a+b} - p - q = \dfrac{pa + qb - pa - pb - qa - qb}{a+b} = -\dfrac{qa + pb}{a+b} < 0$, and the conclusion follows.